# How to use the hardware's 3D texture sampling with a flipbook style volume texture?

Tags: opengl, hlsl, volume-rendering, 3d-texture

[A question sort of addressing the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23006414/3d-texture-in-webgl-three-js-using-2d-texture-workaround) and [another question asking a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617810/how-to-use-3d-texture-in-opengl-and-cg-shaders).

I have a 2D texture that has 12x12 slices of a volume layered in a grid like this:
[image]

What I am doing now is to calculate the offset and sampling based of the 3D coordinate inside the volume using HLSL code myself. I have followed the descriptions found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_rendering#Direct_volume_rendering) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509695%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), where the first link also talks about 3D sampling from a 2D sliced texture. I have also heard that modern hardware have the ability to sample 3D textures.

That being said, I have not found any description or example code that samples the 3D texture. What HLSL, or OpenGL, function can I use to sample this flipbook type of texture? If you can, please add a small example snippet with explanations. If you cant, pointing me to one or the documentation would be appreciated. I have found no sampler function where I can provide the number of layers in the U and V directions so I dont see how it can sample without knowing how many slices are per axis.

If I am misunderstanding this completely I would also appreciate being told so.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: So what are you actually using: DirectX or OpenGL? In case of OpenGL you will most likely write your shaders in GLSL, not HLSL.

Comment: I am using HLSL and DirextX right now, but I could much easier search for the HLSL equivalent is I knew the OpenGL function. Further, I might have to also implement this in OpenGL code at some point.

Comment: "*I have also heard that modern hardware have the ability to sample 3D textures.*" If by "modern", you mean almost any (desktop) GPU made in the last 15 years or so, sure ;)

Comment: @nicolbolas Might be. I am just parroting what I was told.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL has support for true 3D textures for ages (actually 3D texture support already appeared in OpenGL-1.2). With that you upload your 3D texture not as a "flipbook" but simply as a stack of 2D images, using the function `glTexImage3D`. In GLSL you then just use the regular `texture` access function, but with a `sampler3D` and a 3 component texture coordinate vector (except in older versions of GLSL, i.e. before GLSL-1.5/OpenGL-3 where you use `texture3D`).

Comment: Can you confirm then, that there are no flipbook type of 3D texture and as long as I get the data in the format I showed I will have to do it manually? I will see if I can request the data in seperate images instead if that is the case.

Comment: @NoobsDeSroobs: There is indeed no support for a "flipbook format" 3D texture. Any why should there be something like that? That being said, it's pretty easy to set pixel store parameters, namely GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS and GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH so that you can fetch the subimages directly from your flipbook without going through a conversion step first.